# Dual Boot : GNU Grub Screen Freezes

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, windows-11

I just recently installed ubunutu version 22.04. I had Windows 10 pre-installed on my laptop. Now, whenever I boot into my computer, my screen gets stuck on GNU Grub menu option. Everything freezes their, the keyboard stops responding.

But, if I power-up and press F9 a change boot order menu open and if I select from there it works fine then. Both windows and ubuntu are supporting uefi bios.

Any help would be seriously appreciated, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

One method of fixing Grub is to boot into Linux, ensure that the Windows partition is mounted, then run the following command :

```
    sudo os-prober
```

If both your installations were found, run:

```
    sudo update-grub
```

If this didn't help, you could try
[Rescatux & Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/).
One or the other utility might be able to correct your Grub setup.